# When an inductance is connected to an AC supply, the current in the inductor is

Tags: inductance

When an inductance is connected to an AC supply, the current in the inductor is

1. is in phase with the voltage
2. Lags the voltage by 90 degrees.
3. Leads the voltage by 90 degrees.
4. Leads the voltage by 180 degrees.

Comment: Did your search engine fail you?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because no attempt to solve the problem has been made by the asker.

Answer (score 5):

CIVIL

Capacitors: I leads V (and) V leads I in an inductor.

In both cases the phase angle is 90 degrees.

Answer (score 2):

When an alternating-current voltage is connected across an inductor, the phase of the current through the inductor lags the voltage by 90°.

A way to remember this for a capacitor or inductor is the mnemonic CIVIL, where the order of the letters shows you whether the voltage leads the current or vice-versa:

- For a capacitor, the "C" side of the word, "I" comes before "V", so current leads voltage (or voltage lags current).
- For an inductor, the "L" side of the word, "V" comes before "I", so voltage leads current (or current lags voltage).
- In a simple, ideal capacitor or inductor, the phase difference is always 90°.

See Wikipedia on [capacitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#AC_circuits) or [inductors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor#Circuit_theory) for the detail and derivation of this.

Answer (score 1):

Option '2' is the correct one. The property of the Inductance is current through the inductance lags voltage across the inductance by 90 degree. But practically it's not possible, because your supply source & connecting wire had some amount of resistance. So, finally that is a Resistance & Inductance combination therefore current lags the voltage by less than 90 degree.